# github не даёт делать push в репозиторий на нём с локального сайта

Tags: ubuntu, git, github, access

У меня стоит сайт и git на нём. Есть удалённый репозиторий на github. Сначала у меня стоял git remote add origin https://github.com... . git clone... прошёл успешно. Сделал изменения, закоммитил, запуллил - всё нормально. Но push - не даёт делать. При запросе имени в github и проверке пароля пишет:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': nara13
Password for 'https://nara13@github.com': 
remote: Permission to vlad13/tobus-yii2.git denied to nara13.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vlad13/tobus-yii2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Дело в том, что и имя и пароль - заданы верно. На другом, аналогичном компьютере с такой-же UBUNTU 14.04 - никаких проблем нет, и, притом для пользователя nara13.
Пробовал эту проблему решить тем, что удалённый репозиторий переключить с https на ssh следующим образом: git remote add origin git@github.com:vlad13/tobus-yii2.git, а старый https... убрал. Сгенерировал у себя на UBUNTU 14.04 публичный ключ, скопировал его на github для себя публичный ключ. Стало ещё хуже: не даёт ни git clone, ни git pull, ну а тем более git push делать на репозиторий на github'е.
Вот данные, которые удалось получить с компьютера:

```
tchprogrammer@tchprogrammer-G31M-ES2L:/var/www/html/test/tobus-yii2$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tchprogrammer/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: а ключ подключен к репозиторию?

Answer (score 1):

Мои ключи хозяин репозитория на github прописал (то есть включил мой public key в этот репозиторий) и сделал всё правильно всё, что связано с ключами (я же не имею полного доступа к репозиторию, потомучто не являюсь его хозяином и создателем).
Но проблема решилась очень просто, проще некуда:
Я просто перезагрузил компьютер (UBUNTU 14.04) и всё заработало.
При этом, передача (pull, push) происходила по ssh:

```
tchprogrammer@tchprogrammer-G31M-ES2L:/var/www/html/tobus-yii2$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:vlad13/tobus-yii2.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:vlad13/tobus-yii2.git (push)
```

Comment: видимо. мы не перезагрузили сервис sshd после добавления своего ключа на тачку

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, этого не требуется. как и перезагрузка сервера. у автора (была) [какая-то из проблем с ssh-agent](https://chrisjean.com/ubuntu-ssh-fix-for-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key/)